# Guidance with Custom Domain?

Tags: custom-domain

Since custom URLs are only supported in production, I'm nervous "testing" out the setup with a Test Community and Custom URL. It is crucial that I do not affect our production site when testing with the "test" site in production.

I have a "my"force.com domain which is the root for both our Production Site and my "Test" Site/Community (again, all in prod). So

mydomain.force.com/productionActualSite >> our actual site

and

mydomain.force.com/thisOtherOneForTesting >> under construction, not important

I made a custom Domain and it's awaiting a custom URL. I ONLY want the "Test" community to be under this URL. So:

Goal:

mydomain.force.com/productionActualSite >> what already exists, still here

somenewDomain.com/ >> to the new Test Site

I want to designate the "Test" site/community to this domain. If I click on the new custom domain, click "New Custom URL", choose that domain, the "Test" site, and leave path as /, this will not affect the other Site/Community that is also under the "my" domain, right?

It seems like it shouldn't affect the other site, but I've had some unexpected redirects with domains and I'm very nervous doing this in prod, and I want to be 100% sure this will not affect production before hitting that save button. Thank you!

Comment: Yes...it will certainly not cause any issue to other site!

Comment: this may be helpful -- http://cropredysfdc.com/2016/12/23/custom-domain-napili-template/

Comment: thanks!! To both! @cropredy , that was a great resource; I am however still hung up on two things.

1 - that screenshot for the domain is not what I'm using. I'm not using a 'my' domain for the custom domain
2 - Think of this as the master URL for all your communities (up to 50) that Salesforce needs to host your communities. >> I do *not* want the domain associated with ANY other community :(